# get each id image src inside my array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var nameset_array = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
//store my id inside my array.

for(var h = 0; h < nameset_array.length; h++){
   //loop thought the array and get each id image src.
   //is not working.
   //tested alert(nameset_array[h].src), not working too.
    alert(nameset_array[h].attr("src"));
  }
```

i have stored my img id to a array , and i want to get each array name img src , how to do i get each id image src in my array ?

i tested `nameset_array[h].src` , it did't work as well , can anyone teach me how to make this work?

Comment: Where is `nameset_array` ?

Comment: oh sorry i edit it now , the first array was it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var nameset = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
for(var h = 0; h < nameset.length; h++){
   var $img = $('#'+nameset[h]);
   if($img.length > 0)
   {
      alert($($img[0]).attr('src'))
   }    
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ben2beq/1/)

Comment: `if($img)` This will be true even if you check `if($())`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Good catch :) Same applies to `{}`... `$img.length` will do!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, You are 100% right! But few developers prefer to have a check on their end as well :)

Comment: Maybe declare and set a variable with the value of nameset.length outside the loop for better performance?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, But it will alert 'undefined' in case that image is not found...

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah. :) But in this case, we are getting the attribute value not setting it. Hence we needed that. I haven't noticed that in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Do like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var nameset = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
//store my id inside my array.
$( nameset ).each(function( index, val ) {
  console.log($("#"+val).attr("src"));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will not work because you tried to get the `src`-Attribute of an array element which is a string.
So what you've tried is this:

```
"display1".src
```

I bet now you see yourself why this is not working.

In your case you have to find the element before you can "use" it.
In order your nameset_array items are all id's of existing elements you function need just this little change:

```
document.getElementById(nameset_array[h]).src
```

If not check the element exists before you're trying to get informations of it.
Here's a full example:

```
var nameset_array = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
for(var h = 0; h < nameset_array.length; h++) {
    var img = document.getElementById(nameset_array[h]);
    if (img) {
        alert(img.src);
    }
}
```

If you don't need old browser support you may wan't to use a newer posibility which needs less code:

```
["display1", "display2", "display3"].forEach(function(id) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    if (img) {
        alert(img.src);
    }
});
```

```js
var nameset_array = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
for(var h = 0; h < nameset_array.length; h++) {
    var img = document.getElementById(nameset_array[h]);
    if (img) {
        alert(img.src);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="display1" src="http://foo.bar/img1.png"/>
<img id="display2" src="http://foo.bar/img2.png"/>
<img id="displayX" src="http://foo.bar/img3.png"/>
<img id="display4" src="http://foo.bar/img4.png"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

Do it this way

```
var nameset = ["display1", "display2", "display3"];
//store my id inside my array.

for(var h = 0; h < nameset.length; h++){
   //loop thought the array and get each id image src.
   //is not working.
   //tested alert(nameset[h].src), not working too.
    alert(document.getElementById(nameset[h]).src);
  }
```

Comment: Where is `nameset_array` ?

Comment: `nameset_array` is not defined

Comment: Where did you find `nameset_array` ?

Comment: @KeyurSakaria, Earlier comment is gonna get flagged mate :)

Comment: @KeyurSakaria I too flagged that. :)